# Calculate using TextChangeHandler in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating an app for a car parking system using android-studio. I am using `TextChangedHandler` to show the `Total Price` of the ticket after the user enters the `Hours staying`. Price differs according to their `Vehicle type`

Passing of vehicle type from `MainActivity.java` to `Ticket.java` works fine. But when I calculate the price and `setText` to the `Total Price`, it doesn't display the price.

**MainActivity.java** (This passes the type of the vehicle as a string to **Ticket.java** activity)

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    View.OnClickListener {
      CardView mCar, mBike, mWheeler, mOther;
      TextView mTypeCar, mTypeBike, mTypeWheeler, mTypeOther;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCar = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.car);
        mCar.setOnClickListener(this);

        mBike = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.bike);
        mBike.setOnClickListener(this);

        mWheeler = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.wheeler);
        mWheeler.setOnClickListener(this);

        mOther = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.other);
        mOther.setOnClickListener(this);

        mTypeCar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.typeCar);
        mTypeBike = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.typeBike);
        mTypeWheeler = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.typeWheeler);
        mTypeOther = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.typeOther);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.car:
                String car = mTypeCar.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ticket.class);
                i.putExtra("type", car);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.other:
                String other = mTypeOther.getText().toString();
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ticket.class);
                i.putExtra("type", other);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.bike:
                String bike = mTypeBike.getText().toString();
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ticket.class);
                i.putExtra("type", bike);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.wheeler:
                String wheeler = mTypeWheeler.getText().toString();
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ticket.class);
                i.putExtra("type", wheeler);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + v.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

**Ticket.java**(Price is calculated using the vehicle type)

```
    public class Ticket extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView mTotPrice;
    EditText mHours, mVehicleNo;
    Button printTicket;
    String type;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ticket);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        type = i.getStringExtra("type");

        mTotPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalPrice);
        mHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hours);
        mVehicleNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vehicleNO);
        printTicket = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrint);

        TextChangeHandler tch = new TextChangeHandler();
        mHours.addTextChangedListener(tch);
    }

    private void calculate() {
        String stayingHours = mHours.getText().toString();

        try {
            // convert hours to int
            int hoursInInt = Integer.parseInt(stayingHours);
            // store price of each vehicle per hour
            int price = 0;
            if (type.equals("Car")) {
                price = 50;
            } else if (type.equals("Other")) {
                price = 70;
            } else if (type.equals("Bike")) {
                price = 20;
            } else if (type.equals("Tuk-tuk")) {
                price = 20;
            }

            // calculate total price
            int totalPrice = price * hoursInInt;
            mTotPrice.setText(totalPrice);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class TextChangeHandler implements TextWatcher {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable e){
            calculate();
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int after){
        }
    }
}
```

**android_ticket.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Ticket">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Enter no. of hours staying"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.123" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Enter vehicle number"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.322" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Ticket Price(Rs)"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.121"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.632" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="755dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.525" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/hours"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:hint="Select up to 5 hours"
        android:textColor="@color/material_on_background_disabled"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalPrice"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/material_on_background_disabled"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.36"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/title4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.62" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/vehicleNO"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:hint="Vehicle number"
        android:textColor="@color/material_on_background_disabled"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.032" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPrint"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:text="Print Ticket"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.77" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set sting value on mTotPrice
please use this code

```
    mTotPrice.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
```

Answer (score 0):

`mTotPrice.setText(totalPrice)` this wont work cause in `setText()` we require a String as actual parameter ie. `.setText(String)`  and you gave it as `.setText(int)`
So just add THIS

```
mTotPrice.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
```

instead of

```
mTotPrice.setText(totalPrice)
```